How AXI is implemented?
From what i understand AXI is interconnect standard, as far as i understand "interconnect" should be somthing like MUX allowing data pass from same port to different end-points.
Although i understand it is not true , can anyone please explain how the AXI works internaly? and what is the difference in implementation for the different types of AXI (AXI stream, AXI Lite, MM-AXI)
I Hope someone could visualize its structure to me.

https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/1053914?language=en_US

so basicaly AXI is just kind of DMA?

No, AXI is strictly a point-to-point interface that allows two modules to communicate synchronously.
If you want an AXI controller to talk to multiple AXI devices, you'll need a module called "AXI Cross-Connect". It can be configured with one device port that connects to your controller, and N controller ports that connect to your devices. Address decoding is handled inside the cross-connect.
